# Why does adding just one more INNER JOIN to a FROM clause make my SQL query so slow?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join, database-performance

I'm working on a MS SQL 2008 database that came with a view called `AcmeView`.  When I script `AcmeView`, I see that it joins together three other views: `View1`, `View2`, and `View3`.  A coworker asked if I could compose a view that would combine the contents of `AcmeView` with data from another view: `NewView`.

`AcmeView` returns a result set in three seconds; it's constituent views contain tens of thousands of rows each.

`NewView` is a much smaller view; it returns only about two thousand rows each; and it returns its result set in a small fraction of a second.

Therefore, I was disappointed that when I modified `AcmeView` to INNER JOIN with `NewView`, the resulting view takes almost twenty seconds to return its result set.  What could possibly be wrong with the view to make it so slow?

The SELECT statement for `AcmeView` looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    View1
    INNER JOIN View2
        ON View2.foo = View1.foo
    INNER JOIN View3
        ON View3.bar = View2.bar    
    -- Executes in 3 seconds

SELECT *
FROM
    View1
    INNER JOIN View2
        ON View2.foo = View1.foo
    INNER JOIN View3
        ON View3.bar = View2.bar
    INNER JOIN NewView
        ON NewView.qwerty = View1.querty
    -- Executes in 20 seconds; why so long?
```

How can it be that adding in just one more view, `NewView` to my FROM clause slows the query to a crawl and what can I do about it?  Once again `NewView` can be queried in a small fraction of a second.

Comment: What this view does ? How much rows does it contains ?

Comment: You need to have a look at the query execution plan to see what the problem is.

Comment: Indexed views might help here.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard for one JOIN to make that much of a difference.

If the join keys are not sorted the same way - quite possible since one of the "tables" is the result of a set of joins - it will all be either re-sorted or just done in a big Nested Loop.

As @magnus said, if you pull the execution plans for both, you'll probably see what is added pretty easily.
And I'm guessing it is a Nested Loop, where for each row in one table it scans every row in the other.

If looking at execution plans is new to you, check out this highly-voted post:
[How to read an execution plan in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758912/how-to-read-an-execution-plan-in-sql-server)

Comment: Reading the execution plan is giving me a headache; the diagram is gigantic and I've never tried to read one of these before.  Maybe @Mihai's suggestion about using indexed views might help?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon Indexed views are a hassle since they have so many restrictions. I would try to index the table(s) that are problem areas in the execution plan.

Comment: It sounds like you definitely know more about this than I do.  Can you advise me about what I should be looking for in the execution plan and what I might do once I find it?

Comment: Do you know what indexes you have today on those tables?

Comment: Because that can be the other way to look at it... if you have no relevant indexes, that gives obvious things to try.

Comment: `View1`, `View2`, and `View3` all refer to numerous other tables and views.  It's a giant mess.  What I do know is that I can query these three views joined together in a few seconds, but adding a fourth one makes it unacceptably slow.  Even viewing the Execution Plan doesn't make me feel any closer to a solution than when I started out.

Comment: Oh....  I forgot they were views.  Yeah, that is a lot tougher.  Do you have access to the underlying tables directly?  Can you simplify it by getting what you need more directly from - hopefully fewer - tables for the last one?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon For testing purposes only, try writing: `INNER HASH JOIN NewView`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  We are going back to the drawing board to see if there is a better way to get the relevant data.